# **Update** Php file won't load using Apache as a Service

Tags: php, windows, apache

I have installed apache as a service on my Windows 10. I also have installed PHP and have that configured correctly. I'm making this assumption because I can create a PHP file in the htdocs directory with phpinfo() and get the expected results.

I have a PHP file located in htdoc folder (The same file I can run phpinfo() in) and go to `127.0.0.1/my_php_file.php` and I get the error "This site can't be reached"

I have searched the logs for the apache service and there are none there.

****Update****

Here is the file's contents

```
<?php 
    $servername = "test";
?>
```

And it gives me the error "This site can't be reached"

The only error in the network tab has a status of "Failed" when loading the page

[image: Updated Error Message]

Comment: Does placing a file with nothing but `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` work at all in the same location AND does a `index.html` file (same location as well) work too?

Comment: Yes both of those work.

Comment: The file is called test.php and I've verified it is a PHP file

Comment: Going to need to see the contents of `test.php`. Please update the question with that information and correct the file names. It is important when debug a problem like this you use the exact file names and the actions to replicate the issue.

Comment: Okay i will update the question with the code in question, thank you

Comment: If `phpinfo();` works and `echo '<h4>Latest members:</h4>';` does not, then (best guess) you have a permission issue.

Comment: Okay how would you recommend test the permission issue and what would the permission issue be?

Comment: On Windows I have no idea. On Linux / Unix the file needs to be readable by the same `user` as the web server (Apache) is started with. Guessing this [Apache docs page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/windows.html) should help.

Comment: Okay I updated the permissions and i've updated my post to include a new file that won't load as now the echo '<h4>Latest members:</h4> is loading correctly,

Comment: EDIT/UPDATE: I added the require_once("connectvars.php"); to my my_php_file.php and now it will not load.

Comment: What of, `require_once __DIR__ . '/connectvars.php';`? Verify the permissions of connectvars.php. What are the contents of connectvars.php, perhaps there is a syntax error in it? Guessing there is probably a `mysql_connect() or die('Failed');` type of usage in it.

Comment: I will update the post to have the contents of connectvars.php
I also checked the permissions by going to the folder that contains the contents and clicked Properties->Security->and all of the users have Full Control access.

Comment: I have updated the question, any thoughts?

Comment: Please add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of the PHP file. This really sounds like a permissions issue and it also sounds like you have debugging off. You might want to enable that.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of this "This site can't be reached" response? That type of response would imply a DNS-type error, which doesn't make much sense given the fact you can serve other content presumably using the same hostname/protocol. ?!

Comment: Simple suggestion, please remove the closing PHP tag (`?>`) from your PHP only files, The closing PHP tag is only needed to transition from PHP code to non-PHP content (plain-text or HTML, etc) and is discouraged from being used otherwise, as it is known to cause issues like you're experiencing, such as with redirects and other `header()` usage. Sounds like the Webserver s crashing or maybe the browser is adding `https://` instead of `http://` if it is intermittently working with the simple examples you provided.

Comment: @WillB. - I have tried removing the closing PHP tag and I am still receiving the same error.

Comment: @MrWhite - I have updated the post with a screen shot of the error

Comment: @Tigger - I have updated the file to have error_reporting(E_ALL): but not seeing any errors pop up in the console. What do you mean by I may have debugging off?

Comment: You should ensure that "Disable cache" is checked on the "Network" tab in your screenshot. And what is on the "Headers" tab? This error means it's not even reaching your server, let alone the `test.php` file on your server!?

Comment: @MrWhite Goodness I'm so sorry I didn't realize I had the preview tab selected. I have updated the screenshot.

Comment: Curious, the response headers (on the right) do not seem to correspond to what you are seeing in the browser (on the left)? Although you don't have the last `test.php` selected?

Comment: @MrWhite - I have updated the picture.

Comment: The connection reset issue with an text/html response is more telling than just site unavailable. How is your webserver configured? mod_php or PHP-FPM, which type of PHP (NTS or TS, x86/x64), what are the configuration options defined for the webserver and virtual host? I suggest removing what was done and using something like XAMPP or WAMP to give you a base full stack environment of PHP + Apache.